# OpenPGP Signature Packet hashed data

Tags: hash, pgp

RFC 4880 describes the version 4 signature packet, tag 2, as

```
- One-octet signature type.
- One-octet public-key algorithm.
- One-octet hash algorithm.
- Two-octet scalar octet count for following hashed subpacket data.
Note that this is the length in octets of all of the hashed
subpackets; a pointer incremented by this number will skip over
the hashed subpackets.
- Hashed subpacket data set (zero or more subpackets).
- Two-octet scalar octet count for the following unhashed subpacket
data. Note that this is the length in octets of all of the
unhashed subpackets; a pointer incremented by this number will
skip over the unhashed subpackets.
- Unhashed subpacket data set (zero or more subpackets).
- Two-octet field holding the left 16 bits of the signed hash
value.
- One or more multiprecision integers comprising the signature.
```

and i assume that the second to last line means just take the string of the hashed subpacket and hash it with the hash algorithm and take its first 2 bytes. however, no matter what i do, i cannot seem to get it.

I generated this fake key a long time ago

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG v1.39
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=sStS
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

From [pgpdump.net](http://pgpdump.net), i see that the left 2 bytes of the hash (SHA 1) value is `45 24` for the first signature packet and `51 ac` for the second one. i am getting `52 f0` for both. obviously, im not including some information, but what is it? the hashed subpackets are identical, and all of the data before the hashed data are the same as well except they are different types of signature packets (0x13 / 0x18). i have been unable to get either of the correct hash values even when i add/take characters from the data packet. the key im generating is exactly the same as the key shown here except for the hash values.

what is the data that i should be hashing??

the key example up there is made up of `packet 6 + packet 13 + packet 2 + packet 14 + packet 2`. i have tried all sorts of combinations of `packet 6`, `packet 13`, and `packet 2` (from version number to hashed data inclusive), but still cannot find the string that hashes to the correct values

**EDIT**: From Ilmari Karonen's suggestion that i read section 5.2.4, i still cannot get the answer

i have been using:

```
a = entire public key packet, header and all
b = entire user id packet, header and all
c = signature packet '\x04' ... '\x1f' (version ... end of hashed subpacket)
```

and hashing in all sorts of different ways. Depending on what `hash context` and `data` (for the user id: is it just the user info, or is it the entire packet? either way i try does not work) mean, the correct method can be anything, which i still cannot find.

how are the hashes of the body and two trailers combined? is that what `hash context` defines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer can be found in [section 5.2.4, "Computing Signatures"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.2.4).  According to that section, what you actually need to hash is the concatenation of:

- the key packet (with an old-style packet header with a two-byte length — but your sample key packet has that header type already),
- for the first (certification) signature, the constant byte 0xB4, a four-byte number giving the length of the user ID packet body, and the user ID packet body itself,
- for the second (subkey binding) signature, the subkey packet (using the same type of header as for the key packet above),
- a "trailer" consisting of the beginning of the signature packet body, from the version number field to the end of the hashed subpacket data, and
- a final six-byte trailer consisting of the bytes 0x04 and 0xFF, and a four-byte big-endian number giving the length of the "trailer" string from the previous string.

I haven't checked if that will actually produce the correct hashes for your packet, but I believe it should.

Note that I've simplified the description somewhat; you should actually read section 5.2.4 of the RFC carefully to figure out just what goes into the hash under various circumstances, since it appears to depend on many things.

**EDIT:** While simplifying, I accidentally left out some pretty major parts. :(  I've added them in now, hopefully this time I've got everything that's needed.  Alas, I can't really check it now either, and probably won't have much chance of participating here during this week.

(Oh, and yes, I agree, that all looks like an awful mess.  I assume there are reasons for all the quirks, and that it probably looks easier to read in source code form, but that doesn't make it any less messy.)

---

*Ps.* As for "hash context", other places where the term is used, particularly [section 3.7.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.7.1.1), suggest that it basically means an object or data structure that contains the internal state of the hash function and supports methods for providing further input and for finalizing the hash and returning the output. (Most cryptographic hash implementations provide such an API.)

In particular, in various parts of the RFC, it is recommended that several hashes be computed in parallel by maintaining multiple hash contexts (i.e. hash object instances).